# Override std::swap for Proxy classes c++

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I've been assigned to implement a `vector<bool>` class with custom random access iterators, representing each `bool` as a bit in a `unsigned int` array. I'm using a proxy class, which has a pointer to a `unsigned int` and a `index` variable saying which bit is being modified.

So my `vector<bool>`s `operator[]` looks like:

```
BoolVectorProxy operator[](std::size_t index) {
    validate_bounds(index);
    return BoolVectorProxy(&array[index / BLOCK_CAPACITY], index % BLOCK_CAPACITY);
}
```

So far so good - however what happens when we need to, on the iterators ( which also returns `BoolVectorProxy` on the brackets operator and dereference operator), do some swapping?

This code does not compile:

```
Vector<bool> a({true, false});
std::swap(a[0], a[1]);
std::cout << a[0] << " " << a[1] << std::endl;
```

It should print `0 1` obviously but the less-than-pleasant error message says that I can't initialize a non-const reference of type `BoolVectorProxy&` from an `rvalue` of type `BoolVectorProxy`. The error is understandable - it tries to use the default `std::swap` but can't cast my returned `rvalue` to a reference.

How does one solve this?

Comment: Define a namespace-scope swap that is found via ADL. Proper generic code will not use `std::swap` but `using std::swap; swap(a, b);`

Comment: Can you expand your comment to an answer and I'll accept it if it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Columbo ok that was easy - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is declared as:

```
template< class T >
void swap( T& a, T& b );
```

For compilers that aren't MSVC, you can't pass an rvalue into that, and `a[0]` is an rvalue (as is `a[1]`). You can't provide your own specialization of `std::swap` for `BoolVectorProxy` either, since that one would *still* have to take an lvalue reference.

The only solution is to write your own `swap` in the associated namespace, so that it can be found with argument dependent lookup:

```
namespace N  // or whatever
{
    struct BoolVectorProxy { ... };

    // take proxies by value
    void swap(BoolVectorProxy a, BoolVectorProxy b)
    {
        // something like this
        bool tmp = static_cast<bool>(a);
        a = static_cast<bool>(b);
        b = tmp;
    }
}
```

And make an *unqualified* call to `swap`:

```
Vector<bool> a({true, false});
using std::swap;
swap(a[0], a[1]);
```

This is a common enough need that it's helpful to wrap that in:

```
template <typename T>
void adl_swap(T&& a, T&& b) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(std::forward<T>(a), std::forward<T>(b));
}
```

With which you can just have written:

```
Vector<bool> a({true, false});
adl_swap(a[0], a[1]);
```